# UNIX for loop with some options

Tags: unix

I have for loop:

```
 for mnt `cat $file.txt`    
 do    
 grep -h -i -A 3 -B 4 *log | grep -v "10001" >> extrafile.txt   

 done
```

What does -A 3 and -B 4 means?

Comment: See the [man page for grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep). `-A` and `-B` allow you to specify the no of lines to print after and before the matching line.

Answer (score 0):

**A**fter and **B**efore followed by number of lines

Answer (score 0):

After en Before. After and before what?
No wonder the grep is confusing: You don't mention the "${mnt}"  you are searching for. When I improve your script (moving input and output to the end, outside the loop, and using ${mnt}), the script looks like

```
while read -r mnt; do
   grep -h -i -A 3 -B 4 "${mnt}" *log | grep -v "10001"    
done < "${file.txt}" >> extrafile.txt
```

You get the context of every hit from $file.txt and delete all lines with 10001.